# data not displaying for csv import

Tags: php, sql, csv

i am trying to create an upload script where a front end end admin can create file i am Ms-excel and save as CSV and then upload it to the database.

using this script i was able to upload to the database, 
but in trying to display the update table, it dispalyed '0' form the product_id and product_price, product_category and product_name was just empty, i checked the database and it was the same, i even tried uploading through phpmyadmin and it was succesful, but it was still empty[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Au2y.jpg)

am i doing something wrong?
is there a better alternative to this?

```
        if(isset($_POST["upload"]))
        {
         if($_FILES['product_file']['name'])
         {
          $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['product_file']['name']);
          if(end($filename) == "csv")
          {
           $handle = fopen($_FILES['product_file']['tmp_name'], "r");
           while($data = fgetcsv($handle))
           {
            $product_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]);
            $product_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, 
            $data[1]);  
                        $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, 
            $data[2]);
            $product_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[3]);
            $query = "
             UPDATE daily_product 
             SET product_category = '$product_category', 
             product_name = '$product_name', 
             product_price = '$product_price' 
             WHERE product_id = '$product_id'
            ";
            mysqli_query($connect, $query);
           }
           fclose($handle);
           header("location: index.php?updation=1");

          }
          else
          {
           $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select CSV File 
             only</label>';
          }
         }
         else
         {
          $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select 
          File</label>';
         }
        }

        if(isset($_GET["updation"]))
        {
         $message = '<label class="text-success">Product Updating 
         Done</label>';
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM daily_product";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        ?>
```

Using this script i was able to upload to the database, but in trying to display the update table, it displayed '0' form the product_id and product_price, product_category and product_name was just empty, i checked the database and it was the same, i even tried uploading through phpmyadmin and it was successful, but it was still empty
[image]

```
       <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <p><label>Please Select File(Only CSV Formate)</label>
        <input type="file" name="product_file" /></p>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-info" 
       value="Upload" />
       </form>
       <br />

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
         <tr>
          <th>Category</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Product Price</th>
         </tr>
         <?php
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
         {
          echo '
          <tr>
           <td>'.$row["product_category"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["product_name"].'</td>
           <td>'.$row["product_price"].'</td>
          </tr>
          ';
         }
         ?>
        </table>
```

is it possible that the problem is with script or the CSV file,

I tried deleting the table to no avail,

Comment: SQL INJECTION ALERT - Read about using prepared statements

Comment: Are you sure your csv-file is correct. Although check your delimiter-char (default is a commata). And please open your csv-file in a text-editor and add a few lines to your question.